# removing white/grey border in bootstrap 3.3.7 collapsible navbar menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've looked @ a number of links on this site, and nothing seems to work. So hoping you can help!
I am using bootstrap 3.3.7, and using this menu https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.6/docs/components/#navbar as an example/test menu.

I've figured out how to change some of the menu colors, but can seem to figure out how to actually change the 'border' around the menu when it collapses.

[image]

*how* can I get rid of it, and/or customize the color?

(and while I am at it - how can I change the regular & hover foreground & background color of the 'hamburger' menu icon?)

thanks for your help!

Comment: Open the developers tool in your browser, right click on the *hamburger* button, "inspect element". Take a look at the CSS to see what you have to change. Probably `.navbar-toggle { border-color: red }`.

Comment: I found it, didn't work. any other ideas?

Comment: What did you try? Try with `red !important`,

Comment: yes I tried the important tag, didn't work. I don't think I correctly identified what it is I need to change, which is what I need help with. can you please help? thx

Comment: If you don't show us what you tried or what you found, we can't help you.

Answer (score -1):

Try This One but This not relevant For Bootsrap #3 versions.

This is for Bootsrap #4 newest Version

```
 <pre>      <button style="border-color: transparent; " class=" navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span>
        </button>
```